# Sorting of added field to admin generator list

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have joined models like this:

```
// /foo/lib/model/doctrine/PurchasedItemTable.class.php
public function retrievePurchased(Doctrine_Query $q)
{
    $rootAlias = $q->getRootAlias($q);
    $q->innerJoin($rootAlias.'.MainItem mi');
    return $q;
}
```

Also, I've defined the method in generator.yml and one column:

```
// generator.yml
config:
  actions: ~
  fields: ~
  list: 
    table_method:  retrievePurchased
    display: [id, MainItem, created_at, updated_at]
```

It is displayed fine, but it's not sortable. How to add this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function retrievePurchased(Doctrine_Query $q)
{
    $rootAlias = $q->getRootAlias($q);
    $q->innerJoin($rootAlias.'.MainItem mi');
    $q->orderBy('mi.created_at');
    return $q;
}
```

?

Comment: I mean, how to make it sortable in UI? The other table headers are links for sorting, but this one is not.

Comment: Here is good article on that - http://stereointeractive.com/blog/2011/01/08/symfony-1-4-admin-generator-sort-on-custom-column/